# Eclipse DTP on Ubuntu 10.4 flakes out!

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I have a very standard setup.  Ubuntu 10.4 with an `apt-get` to install eclipse.  It gave me Eclipse Version: 3.5.2.  I want to use Data Tools Platform (DTP).  I used the Help|Install New Software... dialog to install it from the repo that comes installed with Eclipse.  It installed, restarted Eclipse, got it configured to work and everything was fine.  Then, I just restarted up my computer and everything is not fine.  The SQL Results window has an ugly "do not enter" icon and it reads:

```
Could not create the view: Plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.internal.ui.view.ResultsView.
```

I found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333514) which has some patches and claims to have a fix..but it's for Eclipse 3.7 and I have no idea where to apply these patches.  I tried reinstalling the plugin (it worked for someone else) and that didn't help.  It actually worked to try a new workspace, but I'm afraid the error will happen again when I exit and the database configuration is a huge pain in the neck to do everytime I get into Eclipse.  It looks like the cause is a messed up link to Lucene.

I basically need someone to tell me how I can clear old SQL runs from my workspace (which apparently prevents Lucene from screwing up) or how to set to find the correct Lucene.

Please help.  This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't think it is necessary to install eclipse on Ubuntu using the apt repository or UbuntuOne.

The reason why Debian folks use apt is because it takes care of all dependencies.  However, eclipse comes with very little *external* dependencies: the JRE and that's all and a lot of *internal* dependencies.  This is why you now have pre-packaged eclipse bundles.

In addition, using apt may force an unwanted eclipse update on your installation when you less need it.

Therefore if you want to stay on the safe side, don't use apt, go to the [eclipse download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and grab the latest stable version.

Since you use DTP, you will need the `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` bundle. The one that weighs 205 MB.  32 or 64 bits.

Stay away from 3.7 till its release date in early summer unless you really need something in the release candidates.

I suspect the problem you have is actually due to an unsatisfied plugin dependency or a plugin version mismatch brought about by the way you installed eclipse.  And the best way to know IMO is to do a fresh install in an eclipsic way rather than an ubuntic way.

**UPDATE**: I also had a look at the bug report you mention. I don't think this applies to your case because the problem seem to originate in a newer version of the lucene plugin and the current version (1.9.1) applies at least till version 3.4 of eclipse.

Comment: +1 Great answer, covers all the bases.  If I could upvote more I would :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually was able to get it working after deleting some directory in my workspace..I'll make a new answer when I have a chance.  I didn't show the entire stack trace, but it did mention the inability to find a method in Lucene as described in the bug report.  It probably is related in some way.  I'm just afraid of upgrading to 3.6 since it appears to be not fixed until 3.7 which as you mentioned is not quite stable yet.

Comment: Do you happen to know of an easy way to delete all files in a certain directory when eclipse starts?

Comment: Sorry for doubting your interpretation then.  As for initial processing, I don't think eclipse offers such a possibility. However what I did in the past in a similar situation is a script eclipse.sh that was doing my initialisation treatment and then calling the eclipse launcher. You might consider this simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Without the entire trace, there was no way for you to know if the issue was related or not.  Anyway.  Maybe I will script it out as you suggest.