# how to tell ubuntu apt-get to install eclipse in other than the default version

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.10

eclipse is installed with apt-get in version 3.5:

> sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform

however I would like to install 3.6.
how to specify that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given Debian distro version, apt has only one version of any given software.
This is because apt tries to solve the problem of dependencies (just like maven in the java
domain if this speaks to you).

If you "lie" about your version, apt won't complain, it's your own risk.  As for eclipse there is little risk as eclipse is only dependent on java versions (for a given os/32-64/gui lib).

In 10.10 the eclipse standard version is 3.5sr2

But in natty narwhal it's 3.6, so you could try to use the

An even safer solution is to add a PPA to your repositories list (synaptic => settings => repository for instance or update manager) there are other PPA that offer helios

Best example:

The [Eclipse ppa](https://edge.launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/debian-package) which has the 3.6 version (follow the PPA configuration instructions if you have never added a ppa before.

This answers your question.  Howewer I tend to discourage using apt for eclipse (see SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010160/eclipse-wont-show-plugins-after-installation/5010244#5010244) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999841/eclipse-dtp-on-ubuntu-10-4-flakes-out/4999952#4999952))

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't. I typed this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:itachi-sama-amaterasu/redeclipse-client sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install redeclipse
```

This doesn't install the updated version, but it helps a bit...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that version 3.6 is published as a package for 10.10, you should try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try to install eclipse. If it's not published you have to wait or build it by yourself.